# Help with direct integral decomposition for locally compact groups

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, locally-compact-groups

This might be a bit of a stupid question but I'm working on a question of Kirillov's "Elements of the Theory of Representations", where he proves that you can decompose a unitary representation of a locally compact group into the direct integral of irreducible representations.

I can understand most of it just fine, but I'm really stuck on figuring out what "the isomorphism from H to $\int_X H_x d\mu_X$ which maps the vector $T(a)\xi \in H$ to the vector function $\xi(x) = T_x(a)\xi_x$" means.

$T_x$ are the set of representations onto some Hilbert spaces $H_x$, which is 'indexed' by a certain set X - I can give more context if needed, but I don't think too many details of the question are relevant. I just don't understand what the actual isomorphism is.

It suggests taking some $\xi_x \in H_x$ but then surely that just fixes the same result $T_x(a)\xi_x$ for any $\xi$? Likewise, it seems to suggest the input is $x \in X$ but then that's not an isomorphism from H.

I think perhaps it could be forming a map from H to each $H_x$ instead.

Again, this is a bit of a dumb question but I can't figure it out for the life of me. I know how to proceed once I've worked out that isomorphism.

Comment: I guess $\xi=\xi(x)$ is a function such that $$\int\limits_X\|\xi(x)\|_{H_x}^2\,d\mu_X(x)<\infty$$   The representation $T$ acts as $(T(a)\xi)(x)=T_x(a)\xi(x).$ The function $T(a)\xi$ is square integrable as $\|(T_x(a)\xi(x)\|_{H_x}=\|\xi(x)\|_{H_x}$

Comment: I ended up trying to use $T(a)\xi \mapsto \int_X T_x(a)\xi_x d\mu(x)$ as the explicit isomorphism - not sure if it’s correct yet or even if it’s an isomorphism :)

Comment: I have tried to explain my point of view  as an answer. I hope it is correct. If so, I wonder if it is digestible and helpful for you. I left aside the measure theoretic explanations of the ingredients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $H_x$ be the family of Hilbert spaces indexed by $x\in X,$ and $\mu_X$ the measure on $X.$ Let $H_X$ be the Hilbert space consisting of families of vectors $\xi=\{\xi_x\},$ $\xi_x\in H_x,$ such that
$$\|\xi\|_{H_X}^2=\int\limits_X\|\xi_x\|^2_{H_x}\,d\mu_X(x) <\infty$$
The inner product in $H_X$ is then well defined as
$$\langle \xi,\eta\rangle_{H_X} =\int\limits_X\langle \xi_x,\eta_x\rangle_{H_x}\,d\mu_X(x)$$

The theorem states: for every representation $G\ni a\to T(a)\in B(H)$ there exists a Hilbert space of the form $H_X,$ and an isometric isomorphism $U:H_X\to H$ such that the representation $\tilde{T}(a):=U^{-1}T(a)U$ (equivalent to $T$), acting on $H_X,$ is of the form
$$\tilde{T}(a)\xi =\int\limits_XT_x(a)\xi_x\,d\mu_X(x)\qquad (*)$$
where $T_x$ are inequivalent irreducible representations of the group.
The equality $(*)$ is defined in the weak sense, i.e. as
$$\displaylines{\langle\tilde{T}(a)\xi,\eta\rangle_{H_X}  \\ =\int\limits_X\langle T_x(a)\xi_x,\eta_x\rangle_{H_x}\,d\mu_X(x)}$$

**Remark** If the representation $T$ is finite dimensional then $X$ is a finite set, and the measure $\mu_X$ is determined by the multiplicity of a given irreducible subrepresentation $T_x$ in $\tilde{T},$ i.e. by equivalence in $T.$

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! Although Kirillov is a great author, this level of detail is far more useful for my level than his explanations.

Comment: You welcome. Kirillov is pretty concise, as I remember.